# Internet connectivity for a playn multiplayer action game

Tags: multitasking, multiplayer, playn

The short story: me and friend are making a multiplayer action game and we thought playn would be great for this. Android, java and HTML5 support is the most important ones but we don't want to cut out the others if not necessary.

The problem is now when we want to implement the networking part of it. We have implemented our own capable server and thought we would use long polling http requests for communication. We estimate now we need some way to have one thread running for the communication that use messages and two multithread safe queues. One queue for incoming messages that the update() part can consume from and one queue for outgoing messages to the server.

Is there any way to implement this without losing platform support? Or any other idea how we can implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PlayN currently has no cross-platform support for persistent socket connections to a server. You will need to implement your own cross-platform abstraction. You can use WebSockets for the HTML5 backend, and you can look for a WebSockets library for Android and whatever other platforms you intend to support.

You can also use the [Nexus library](https://github.com/threerings/nexus), which is designed to work with PlayN and provide client/server communication. However, it raises the level of abstraction substantially beyond passing simple messages between the client and server, so it might be easier to just implement your own simple WebSockets based communication than to learn how Nexus works.

Comment: What about the threading problem? How can you implement the threads for the different platforms?

About websockets, yes I guess that will be the best solution to the problem. Do you think it would be a good idea for us to implement it in a good way so it could be patched into playn later?

Comment: For platforms that require threads, you use the native platform APIs to create your threads. In the web browser, you don't need threads to use WebSockets, the browser handles things for you.

Comment: Also, you don't need to structure things so that they can be patched into PlayN. You can simply create your own cross platform network API that uses the same approach to cross platform handling and the same platforms as PlayN, and games that want to use your library can. That's what Nexus does. It doesn't have to *be* a part of PlayN.